# the definition of container_of macro

Tags: macros, linux-kernel, c-preprocessor

instead of defining container_of as:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({ \
            const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);
            (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

Why won't this simply work :

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({ \
                    (type *)( (char *)(ptr) - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

what's the usage of first line in the definition?

Answer (score 9):

It adds some level of type safety.  With your second version, I could pass anything in for ptr and it would compile fine.  With the kernel's version, you'll at least get a warning if you pass in a pointer for `ptr` that doesn't match the type of `type.member`.